# Sink pivot rod is stuck, appears to be attached to sink stopper

Tags: sink

I removed the pivot rod nut but the pivot will not come out like is shown on many videos.  The pivot rod appears to be attached to the sink stopper, I can feel tension on the sink stopper when trying to remove the rod, any ideas?.[image]

Comment: Can you turn it counterclockwise? I've seen a few that screw into the stopper but those are usually on all brass fixtures, not PVC.

Comment: Take a wider picture please, showing the whole rod.

Answer (score 1):

It may have a chunk of hair on it wiggle up and down while pulling out. Be prepared to pull the trap as everything stuck on this shaft will possibly slip down 1 wife , 3 girls , 6 granddaughters and all but one has very long hair , I have to clean drains in my current house all the time I liked my 3 bath house better I did not have to do it so often.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  The rod was not screwed into the stopper but in tuning the rod counterclockwise as suggested it broke up debris that then allowed the rod to come out.  Our young kids must have put stuff down the drain, as Ed suggested.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Tons of hair stuck is usually the problem!
I started by using a plastic “hair snake” to remove hair and gunk. I then twisted and turned the stopper both ways. Tapped on the ball of the rod with a hammer.
Finally after much effort, I yanked out the stopper and rod saw that the rod had corroded and that’s what prevented me from removing the stopper.
Will be inexpensive and a breeze to put in a new stopper and pop up rod. [image]